# ANDROID - after click button, go to landscape page

Tags: android, xml, orientation, landscape

I have a problem....

First, I go to **main page**. After I click **MASUK button**, I hope I can go to **BOARD VIEW which have landscape orientation**.  ***But I got error***.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Button masuk;

@Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    masuk = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_masuk);
    masukClicked();
 }

 void masukClicked() {
    masuk.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Board.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
 }
}
```

**BOARD VIEW in this class**

```
public class Board extends Activity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.board);
    }
}
```

**RESOURCES :**

[image]

**ANDROID MANIFEST :**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.snakeladder"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" 
    >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"

        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.snakeladder.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Board" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**I want to go to landscape view after click button. The landscape view is inside layout-land folder**

Comment: `board` layout load only when device is in landscape mode otherwise system search for `board` layout inside `layout` folder.

Comment: so, I just put board layout in layout folder.. Is the problem finish ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<activity
            android:name=".Board"
android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
        </activity>
```

add this code it'll do the work

Comment: thanks, man. You will get what you want. But you must waiting 10 minutes, lol

Comment: @AndikaK what i didn't get you? now i got you

Comment: I don't understand. You will get best answer I mean